# Global Error Handling on AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, error-handling, antiforgerytoken

I have this ASP.Net core web app. I've configured some custom error handlers in `Startup.cs`. Here you can see:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), app =>
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/api/error-{0}");
    });

    app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), app =>
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error-{0}");
    });

    //...
}
```

Then there is a controller which has `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` above it.

The problem is that when `AntiForgeryToken` fails the valdation, request get responded with status code 400 and my custom error handler is not working. If I send the correct `AntiForgeryToken` or simply remove `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` attribute, then the custom error handler works just fine.

Is there a way to make `[AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]` failure result to use the global error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#SOLVED** The problem occurres because the action of of custom error handler itself is inside the same controller; Thus the error handler action method itself required ant-forgery token! solved by adding `[IgnoreAntiForgeryToken]` above error handler action method.